# CSS Background Image not appearing on website

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website from `CSS` and `HTML`. I'm up to the point of adding a background image to my website. The trouble is, the image isn't showing up as the website's background.

My CSS code:

```css
.bg {
  background: url('https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg?i10c=img.resize(height:160)');
  height: 50%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Just ask me if you need any more code from my website.

> Edit: This is not a clone, I've tried every other solution that I've come across on here, and nothing works.

Comment: Try to add `height` in px

Comment: Will try now @AnzilkhaN

Comment: `.bg{ height: 250px;}`

Comment: to make visible any element it required to have width and height. So here once you will apply the right width & height you will get the background. Height : 50% not actually applied on your element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works fine if you use `fixed height:`**

In the below case I have used `100px;`

```css
  .bg {
    background: url('https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg?i10c=img.resize(height:160)');
    height: 100px;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg">

</div>
```

But if you want it to be 100% of the screen you can always go with `100vh`

```css
.bg {
  background: url('https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg?i10c=img.resize(height:160)');
  height: 100vh;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

</div>
```

*If you want to know more about `vh` visit this **[link](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)***

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: @InterRadical use `vh` i have updated my answer follow the second fiddle.

Comment: @InterRadical if you want it to be `50%` of the screen height go with `50vh` change your code as per your need tweak the values and you will learn much more about `vh` and `vw`.

Answer (score 0):

The background image for a page can be set like this:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

so maybe you can change your code become :

```css
  .bg {
    background-image: url('https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg?i10c=img.resize(height:160)');
    height: 100px;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add background image to whole HTML Page then use body tag.

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg");
}
```

and if you want to add background to specific class then use this

```
.bg {
    background-image: url('https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg');
}
```

in that adjust your height accordingly. if you want to add to full class then use 
height:100% else adjust it with your own condition.

Answer (score 0):

The image that the OP refers to is a resized version of the original.  This solution uses the original image along with CSS that uses a height of 100vh (as recommended by @weBBer) and auto for the width.  The background position remains with a center value. It seems needless to repeat the image so the CSS uses no-repeat.  This works with Google Chrome (version 49).

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg);
  width:auto;
  height:100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

The result is a centered image that fills the page due to background-size property being set to [cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) as well as the height property set to 100vh, i.e. 100% of the view port height; see more about this and other measurements [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/7-css-units-you-might-not-know-about--cms-22573).

If you only wanted to fill the portion within the dimensions of the DIV then you could alter the CSS and replace background-size property with object-fit, as follows:

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/12047219/thumb/10.jpg);
  height:480px;
  margin-left:auto;width:100%;margin-right:auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit:cover;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```